# Meteor Wont save a variable that retrieves data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection within my `MongoDB`, and i'm trying to extract data from a collection, and save it as a global variable (outside the client code) for further use.

my main .js

```
Test = new Mongo.Collection('test');
dataset = Test.find().fetch();  
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.nvd3line.rendered = function () {
 ....i use here the dataset variable }
```

I'm pretty sure that i  have  data within the collection *test*, since within the console

```
i typed  within console:
    Test.find().fetch();
    [Object XXXXXXXXXXX"_id: MongoID.ObjectIDis_test: "Test"__proto__: Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

I also checked through the `mongo` CLI using "*show collections*", and the required collection: *test* shows plenty of data.

My problem is that `dataset` isn't being saved as a global variable, hence i cant use it within my app on the Template.helper code (*is.client* part).

Any help on that would be awesome!!!!

Comment: try to console log your dataset, data is probably not ready yet when you're using it on rendered

Comment: Thanks, thogh im not sure how to do that, i entered the meteor shell, dataset do exist there (on the server), so im not sure how to refresh it?

Comment: console log on your function Template.nvd3line.rendered. Dunno why you re passing by shell, you want to know if data is avaible client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
Test = new Mongo.Collection('test');

dataSet = function() {
    return Test.findOne({});
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.nvd3line.rendered = function () {
   //work with dataSet here
   var myDataSet = dataSet();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't do the Job :(

Comment: can you please add more code snippet, why you need global variable, and what didn't worked ?

Comment: Thanks @Salman Hasni , though im note really sure which part of my code you want me to add?